# posenet: image varied by the number of people

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner of coding though need to figure out the function of POSENET somehow.
Basically what I want to do is each different GIF image will be loaded by the number of people who are front of webcam using POSENET.
I tried to find out 'multi-pose' but it was theoretical.

This is my code that I figured by myself so far.
Apparently it is not working. 
Could you let me know what is the problem, even the basic problem? (eg; load image etc...)

---

```js
let video;
let poseNet;
let poses = [];


var firstImg = "posenet/1person.gif";
var secondImg = "posenet/2people.gif";
var thridImg = "posenet/3people.gif";
var fourthImg = "posenet/4people.gif";
var fifthImg = "posenet/5people.gif";
var sixthImg = "posenet/6people.gif";
var seventhImg = "posenet/7people.gif";



function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  poseNet = ml5. poseNet(video. modelReady);
  poseNet. on('pose', gotPoses);
}

function gotPoses(poses){
  console.log(poses);
}

function gotResults(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  if(result) {
    if (object > 0) {
      imgStart(detections)
    }
  }
}

function imgStart(detections){
  if(object[0]){
    document.getElementById("firstImg");
  }
  else if(object[1]){
    document.getElementById("secondImg");
  }
  else if(object[2]){
  document.getElementById("thirdImg");
  }
  else if(object[3]){
  document.getElementById("fourthImg");
  }
  else if(object[4]){
  document.getElementById("fifthImg");
  }
  else if(object[5]){
  document.getElementById("sixthImg");
  }
  else if(object[6]){
  document.getElementById("sevnethImg");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the java tag. This is javascript code, which have no relationship to java.

Comment: please define "is not working".